# Disable Column in edit mode only Syncfusion GRID

Tags: javascript, syncfusion

I try to disable column only in edit mode with **EJ2 Grid Syncfusion**
Columns Code

```
columns: [
            { type: 'checkbox', field: 'CheckBox', width: 50 },
            { field: 'id', isPrimaryKey: true, visible: false, headerText: 'id', textAlign: 'Right', width: 120, type: 'number' },
            {
                field: 'modulID', headerText: 'Nama Modul', width: 80, validationRules: { required: true }, allowEditing :false ,
                foreignKeyField: 'id', foreignKeyValue: 'modulName', dataSource: modulComplete
            },
            {
                field: 'departmentID', headerText: 'Department', width: 80, validationRules: { required: false },
                foreignKeyField: 'id', foreignKeyValue: 'departmentName', dataSource: department
            },
            {
                field: 'pegawaiApprover1ID', headerText: 'Pegawai Approver 1', width: 80, validationRules: { required: false },
                foreignKeyField: 'id', foreignKeyValue: 'nama', dataSource: pegawai
            },
            {
                field: 'pegawaiApprover2ID', headerText: 'Pegawai Approver 2', width: 80, validationRules: { required: false },
                foreignKeyField: 'id', foreignKeyValue: 'nama', dataSource: pegawai
            },
            { field: 'officePerusahaanID', visible: false, headerText: 'officeid', textAlign: 'Right', width: 120, type: 'number' },
            { field: 'isApprovedByApprover', width: 40, headerText: 'isApprovedByApprover', type: 'checkbox' },
            { field: 'isApprovedByGA', width: 40, headerText: 'isApprovedByGA', type: 'checkbox' },
            { field: 'isApprovedByCheckin', width: 40, headerText: 'isApprovedByCheckin', type: 'checkbox' },
        ],
```

But it will disable the column from add action too

Any info how to disable column on edit mode only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have analysed your query and you can achieve your requirement by enabling the isIdentity column property of the grid. Please find the code snippet below,

```
columns: [
            { type: 'checkbox', field: 'CheckBox', width: 50 },
            { field: 'id', isPrimaryKey: true, visible: false, headerText: 'id', textAlign: 'Right', width: 120, type: 'number' },
            {
                field: 'modulID', headerText: 'Nama Modul', width: 80, validationRules: { required: true }, allowEditing :false , isIdentity: true,
                foreignKeyField: 'id', foreignKeyValue: 'modulName', dataSource: modulComplete
            },
        ],
```

Please get back to us if you need further assistance.

Regards,

Hariharan

Answer (score 0):

My code was different but for me what did the trick (to disable the column on edit mode and to enable it on add action) was to add:

```
isPrimaryKey: true
```

My column definition in html is:

```
 <e-column field="name" isPrimaryKey="true" headerText="Name" width="100" type="string" [validationRules]="{ required: true, min: [this.nameValidation, 'Name already in use'] }">
```